# pass array of slug from pagination in gatsby-node.js

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I have an array that will make the layout's header change according to the slug or the `location.pathname`, now I make it manually, which is not good.

I do it like this

```
let pathnames = [
      '/',
      '/kurikulum/',
      '/kurikulum/2',
      `/pengembangan-diri/`,
      '/pengembangan-diri/2',
      '/pengembangan-diri/3',
      '/pengembangan-diri/4',
      '/statistik/',
      '/teknologi/',
      '/ekonomi/',
      '/desain/',
      '/corona/',
      '/2',
      '/3',
      '/4'
    ]

if (pathnames.includes(location.pathname)) {
      header = ()}
```

and here is my `gatsby-node.js`

```
 const desainPageResults = graphql(`
        {
            desainPageResults: allCockpitMarkdown(filter: {childMarkdownRemark: {frontmatter: {title: {ne: ""}, tags: {eq: "desain"}}}}) {
        edges {
          node {
            childMarkdownRemark {
              frontmatter {
                title
                slug
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
        }
    `).then(result => {
        if (result.errors) {
            Promise.reject(result.errors);
        }

        // Create blog pages
        paginate({
      createPage, 
      items: result.data.desainPageResults.edges, 
      itemsPerPage: 5, 
      pathPrefix: '/desain', 
      component: path.resolve('./src/templates/desain.jsx'),
      // const paginateTemplate = path.resolve('./src/templates/paginate.jsx')
  
    })
    });
    const teknologiPageResults = graphql(`
        {
            teknologiPageResults: allCockpitMarkdown(filter: {childMarkdownRemark: {frontmatter: {title: {ne: ""}, tags: {eq: "teknologi"}}}}) {
        edges {
          node {
            childMarkdownRemark {
              frontmatter {
                title
                slug
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
        }
    `).then(result => {
        if (result.errors) {
            Promise.reject(result.errors);
        }

        // Create blog pages
        paginate({
      createPage, 
      items: result.data.teknologiPageResults.edges, 
      itemsPerPage: 5, 
      pathPrefix: '/teknologi', 
      component: path.resolve('./src/templates/teknologi.jsx'),
      // const paginateTemplate = path.resolve('./src/templates/paginate.jsx')
  
    })
    });
    const coronaPageResults = graphql(`
        {
            coronaPageResults: allCockpitMarkdown(filter: {childMarkdownRemark: {frontmatter: {title: {ne: ""}, tags: {eq: "desain"}}}}) {
        edges {
          node {
            childMarkdownRemark {
              frontmatter {
                title
                slug
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
        }
    `).then(result => {
        if (result.errors) {
            Promise.reject(result.errors);
        }

        // Create blog pages
        paginate({
      createPage, 
      items: result.data.coronaPageResults.edges, 
      itemsPerPage: 5, 
      pathPrefix: '/corona', 
      component: path.resolve('./src/templates/corona.jsx'),
      // const paginateTemplate = path.resolve('./src/templates/paginate.jsx')
  
    })
    });
    const statistikPageResults = graphql(`
        {
            statistikPageResults: allCockpitMarkdown(filter: {childMarkdownRemark: {frontmatter: {title: {ne: ""}, tags: {eq: "statistik"}}}}) {
        edges {
          node {
            childMarkdownRemark {
              frontmatter {
                title
                slug
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
        }
    `).then(result => {
        if (result.errors) {
            Promise.reject(result.errors);
        }


        paginate({
      createPage, 
      items: result.data.statistikPageResults.edges, 
      itemsPerPage: 5, 
      pathPrefix: '/statistik', 
      component: path.resolve('./src/templates/statistik.jsx'),

  
    })  
    });
    const kurikulumPageResults = graphql(`
        {
            kurikulumPageResults: allCockpitMarkdown(filter: {childMarkdownRemark: {frontmatter: {title: {ne: ""}, tags: {eq: "kurikulum"}}}}) {
        edges {
          node {
            childMarkdownRemark {
              frontmatter {
                title
                slug
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
        }
    `).then(result => {
        if (result.errors) {
            Promise.reject(result.errors);
        }


        paginate({
      createPage, 
      items: result.data.kurikulumPageResults.edges, 
      itemsPerPage: 5, 
      pathPrefix: '/kurikulum', 
      component: path.resolve('./src/templates/kurikulum.jsx'),

  
    })  
    });
    const ekonomiPageResults = graphql(`
        {
            ekonomiPageResults: allCockpitMarkdown(filter: {childMarkdownRemark: {frontmatter: {title: {ne: ""}, tags: {eq: "ekonomi"}}}}) {
        edges {
          node {
            childMarkdownRemark {
              frontmatter {
                title
                slug
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
        }
    `).then(result => {
        if (result.errors) {
            Promise.reject(result.errors);
        }


        paginate({
      createPage, 
      items: result.data.ekonomiPageResults.edges, 
      itemsPerPage: 5, 
      pathPrefix: '/ekonomi', 
      component: path.resolve('./src/templates/ekonomi.jsx'),

  
    })  
    });
    const pengembanganDiriPageResults = graphql(`
        {
            pengembanganDiriPageResults: allCockpitMarkdown(filter: {childMarkdownRemark: {frontmatter: {title: {ne: ""}, tags: {eq: "pengembangan-diri"}}}}) {
        edges {
          node {
            childMarkdownRemark {
              frontmatter {
                title
                slug
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
        }
    `).then(result => {
    
        if (result.errors) {
            Promise.reject(result.errors);
        }


        paginate({
      createPage, 
      items: result.data.pengembanganDiriPageResults.edges, 
      itemsPerPage: 5, 
      pathPrefix: '/pengembangan-diri', 
      component: path.resolve('./src/templates/pengembangan-diri.jsx'),

  
    })
    });

    const allItems = graphql(
        `{
          allCockpitMarkdown(filter: {childMarkdownRemark: {frontmatter: {title: {ne: ""}}}}) {
            edges {
              node {
                childMarkdownRemark {
                  frontmatter {
                    title
                    slug
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
            allMarkdownRemark(filter: {frontmatter: {title: {ne: ""}}}) {
              edges {
                node {
                  frontmatter {
                    title
                    slug
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          allCockpitAuthors(filter: {lang: {eq: "id"}}) {
            edges {
              node {
                title {
                  slug
                  value
                }
              }
            }
          }
        
        allCockpitOldpage(filter: {lang: {eq: "id"}}) {
          edges {
            node {
              title {
                value
              }
            }
          }
        }
        }
          `
         ).then(result => {
        if (result.errors) {
          console.log(result.errors)
          reject(result.errors)
        }

        
        paginate({
          createPage, 
          items: result.data.allCockpitMarkdown.edges, 
          itemsPerPage: 10, 
          pathPrefix: '/',  
          component: PaginateTemplate,
        })

        const pages = result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges
        pages.forEach(( post,index ) => {
          createPage({
            path: `/${post.node.frontmatter.slug}/`,
            component: markdown,
            context: {
              slug: post.node.frontmatter.slug,
              previous: index === 0 ? null : pages[index - 1].node,
              next: index === (pages.length - 1) ? null : pages[index + 1].node,
            },
          });
          createPage({
            path: `${post.node.frontmatter.slug}/amp/`,
            component: amp,
            context: {
              slug: post.node.frontmatter.slug,
              previous: index === 0 ? null : pages[index - 1].node,
              next: index === (pages.length - 1) ? null : pages[index + 1].node,
            }
          });
        })
        const oldpage = result.data.allCockpitOldpage.edges
        oldpage.forEach(( {node} ) => {
          createPage({
            path: `/${node.title.value}`,
            component: oldPageTemplate,
            context: {
              slug: node.title.value
            },
          })
        })
    
      })
    
  return Promise.all([allItems, desainPageResults,statistikPageResults, kurikulumPageResults, ekonomiPageResults,pengembanganDiriPageResults,coronaPageResults,teknologiPageResults ]);
}
```

I am confused on how to do it.

Comment: You could pass it via `pageContext`: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/creating-and-modifying-pages/#pass-context-to-pages

Answer (score 0):

Your `gatsby-node.js` is a bit confusing to me. However, what I would try is to check before your `createPage` if the page slug exists in your array of `pathnames`. If so, you should send via `pageContextApi` a parameter to render or not the `<Header>` component.

As an example:

```
paginate({
  createPage, 
  items: result.data.allCockpitMarkdown.edges, 
  itemsPerPage: 10, 
  pathPrefix: '/',  
  component: PaginateTemplate,
  context: {
    shouldRenderHeader: pathnames.includes(slug)
    // other stuff
   }
})
```

This will set as a boolean (`true`/`false`) the `shouldRenderHeader` context. In the previous snippet, `PaginateTemplate` will have this information inside `props.pageContext`.